# Is the map $\omega\mapsto (X(\omega),Y(\omega))$ measurable with respect to $\sigma(X,Y)$?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Definitions: We have a measure space $(\Omega,\sigma(X,Y),\mu)$ where $X,Y$ are maps from $\Omega$ to some measure space $(S,\Sigma,m)$. Here $\sigma(X,Y)$ is the smallest sigma algebra that makes both $X,Y$ measurable. Now is it true that the map $g:\Omega \to (S^2,\Sigma^2,m\times m)$ given by $\omega\mapsto (X(\omega),Y(\omega))$ is measurable? (Here $S^2$ is endowed with typical product measure/sigma algebra).

So I have to show that for any $A\in \Sigma\times\Sigma$, $g^{-1}(A) \in \sigma(X,Y)$ but I just don't see how I could express $g^{-1}(A)$ in terms of $\sigma(X,Y)$ measurable sets. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product $\sigma$-algebra is generated by sets of the form $B\times C$ for $B,C\in\Sigma$.  So it suffices to show that $g^{-1}(B\times C)\in \sigma(X,Y)$ for any $B,C\in\Sigma$ (the set of $A$ such that $g^{-1}(A)\in \sigma(X,Y)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, so if it contains all sets of the form $B\times C$, it contains the entire product $\sigma$-algebra).  You should be able to finish from here by thinking about what it means for $\omega\in\Omega$ to be an element of $g^{-1}(B\times C)$.

Comment: Ah, I was forgetting you could always simplify the problem by considerting simpler objects! Clearly $g^{-1}(B\times C) = X^{-1}(B) \cap Y^{-1}(C)$ so we are done. Thanks a lot :)